# How to run CloudFlare Argo client ("cloudflared") on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, cdn, cloudflare, buildpack, cloudflare-argo

How would you recommend running CloudFlare's Argo client `cloudflared` on Heroku?

In particular, how would you lock down the web dyno's `$PORT` so it rejects HTTP traffic that does not originate from the local `cloudflared` client?